# Which element is dropped (jquery draggable)?

Tags: jquery, draggable, drag-and-drop

I just started working with jQuery draggable, but I couldn't find anything in the API documentation to identify which element has been dropped to an area. The sample scripts work with one but I need way more draggable divs.

```
 $( "#droppable2" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
      .find( "p" )
        .html( "What IS DROPPED HERE?");
  }
});
```

Actually I want to catch the id of dropped element for further use, and update the .html() to the contents of the div.

//I'm trying to work with this library: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$( ui.draggable )` instead of `$( this )`

```
var id = $( ui.draggable ).prop('id');
```